# Create a database and make it "current"

Tags: postgresql

I have an sql-script that recreates my unit-testing database. At the moment it's run with `\i <path_to_my_script>`. It goes like

```
// create user, give him some priveleges

CREATE DATABASE my_database;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id UUID primary key,
  data json
);
```

But `my_table` is created in `postgres` database, not in `my_database`.

How can I specify that `my_table` should be created in `my_database`?

---

I use postgresql 10.5.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the database to work in at connection time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10338367/544342

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 'psql', you can change the database you are connected to by using the `\c` metacommand.  So it would look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
\c my_database
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id UUID primary key,
  data json
);
```

This works from '\i' included files.  When the \i file is done, you will be left in the new database unless you do something to change back to the old one.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you always connect to one specific database. Your entire session addresses only that one database (a.k.a. catalog).

So you cannot create *and* define a new database/catalog in one session. Creating the empty database and then filling it needs to be done in **two separate phases** using two different connections.

Phase One: Connect to an existing database such as the usual default database named `postgres`. Execute your `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Phase Two: Get a new connection to this new database. Add your table definitions. Populate your rows.

I suggest using a database migration tool such as *Flyway* or *Liquibase* for handling and executing SQL scripts to do the Phase Two work.